# XSD problem importing another namespace and using its type declarations

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting used to XML Schemas and tried to import another schema into my own.

The initial schema file `test.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
  targetNamespace="test"
  xmlns="test"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" >

    <xs:complexType name="Test">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="test-import" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The importing schema `test2.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
  targetNamespace="test2"
  xmlns="test2"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:test="test"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" >

    <xs:import namespace="test" schemaLocation="./test.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="project">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="test" type="test:Test" />

                <xs:element name="test2" type="Model" />
                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Model">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="model-test" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

And finally the test.xml file which imports the namespace `test.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file xmlns="test2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="./test2.xsd">

    <test>
        <test-import>Text</test-import>
    </test>
    
    <test2>
        <model-test>Text</model-test>
    </test2>

</file>
```

In the end the tag test2 would work fine but at `<test-import>Text</test-import>` i would get the error message:

````
 - test-import

One of the following is expected:
 - test-import

Error indicated by:
 {test}
with code:xml(cvc-complex-type.2.4.a)```
````

Comment: I see a couple of mistakes in your XML. Root tag  `<file>` should be `<project>`, according to test2.xsd. Also, your XML only has 1 namespace declaration but it needs 2, otherwise you cannot put the `<test>` tag into namespace 'test2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many issues to list out, but below you can find all mistakes corrected such that your XML will validate successfully against your XSD.

### See also

- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)
- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [Why are XML namespaces HTTP addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38271786/290085)

## File set with all errors corrected

### test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://example.com/test2" 
         xmlns:test="https://example.com/test"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://example.com/test2 test2.xsd">
  <test>
    <test:test-import>Text</test:test-import>
  </test>
  <test2>
    <model-test>Text</model-test>
  </test2>
</project>
```

### test2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="https://example.com/test2"
    xmlns="https://example.com/test2"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:test="https://example.com/test"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:import namespace="https://example.com/test" schemaLocation="test.xsd" />

  <xs:element name="project">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="test" type="test:Test" />
        <xs:element name="test2" type="Model" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="Model">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="model-test" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

### test.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="https://example.com/test"
    xmlns="https://example.com/test"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified" >

  <xs:complexType name="Test">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="test-import" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: thx man, that really helped my out!